Finding value of convergent infinite series in the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{A_n G_n}$
Let $\left\{A_n\right\}$ be an arithmetic sequence and $\left\{G_n\right\}$ be a geometric sequence with common ratio $r$ such that $|r|>1$. I would like to find the value of infinite series that takes the form
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{A_nG_n}.$$
It can be shown that this series converge, using the ratio test.
A famous example is
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(2^n)}=\ln2.$$
However, is there a way to generalize it to any product of arithmetic and geometric sequence in the denominator? I think the Bailey–Borwein–Plouffe formula gave me some inspiration. I have read an elementary proof of the formula here. For $a<8$ and $a \neq{0}$, we have
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+8n)16^n}=2^{\frac{a}{2}} \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}\frac{x^{a-1}}{1-x^{8}} \mathrm{d}x.$$
If furthermore $a$ is an integer, then the integrand in the right side is a rational function and hence the integral can be solved. I want to see if we can generalize this to find any infinite series that takes the form
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+nd)r^n}$$
where $a,d,r$ are real numbers, $|r|>1$ and $a+nd \neq 0$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$.
Thank you in advance!

As long as $\left|\dfrac{x^d}{r}\right|<1$,
$$\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{(a+nd)r^n}=\int_0^1x^{a-1}\sum_{n\geq 1}\left(\dfrac{x^{d}}{r}\right)^n\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{d+a-1}}{r-x^d}\,\mathrm dx$$
Furthermore,
$$\int_0^1 \dfrac{x^{d+a-1}}{r-x^d}\,\mathrm dx=\dfrac{1}{r(a+d)}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a+d}{d};\frac{a}{d}+2;\frac{1}{r}\right)$$
iff $r\neq 0$ and $a\neq -d$.
To summarize,
$$\color{brown}{\boxed{\color{black}{\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{1}{(a+nd)r^n}=\dfrac{1}{r(a+d)}\, _2F_1\left(1,\frac{a+d}{d};\frac{a}{d}+2;\frac{1}{r}\right)}}}\,,\enspace |r|> 1\,\wedge\, a+nd\neq 0,\,\forall n$$

To help the OP, ${}_2 F_1$ is the Gauss hypergeometric function.

Thanks a lot. I only know few about hypergeometric function, but I can directly expand the expression at the R.H. and get back the L.H. without using the integral form. So its perfectly fine for me :)

This is also the definition of a special function
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(a+nd)\,r^n}=\frac{\Phi
   \left(\frac{1}{r},1,\frac{a+d}{d}\right)}{d r}$$ where $\Phi(.)$ is the Hurwitz-Lerch transcendent function.
In the case where $m=\frac{a+d}{d}$ is a positive integer, the formulae are quite nice. Let
$$F_m=\frac 1 r \Phi\left(\frac{1}{r},1,m\right)$$ The first are
$$F_2=-r \log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)-1$$
$$F_3=-r^2 \log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)-r- \frac{1}{2}$$
$$F_4=-r^3 \log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)-r^2-\frac{r}{2}-\frac{1}{3}$$
$$F_5=-r^4 \log \left(1-\frac{1}{r}\right)-r^3-\frac{r^2}{2}-\frac{r}{3}-\frac{1} {4}$$ where the patterns are quite clear.
$$G_m=F_m-r\, F_{m-1}=-\frac 1{m-1}$$

Thanks a lot! I think when $k= \frac{a}{d}$ is a positive integer, it can be presented in a more fundamental way. The problem becomes $\frac{1}{d} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+k)r^n}$
In this case, we can use Maclaurin series of $\ln(1-x)$ for $|x|<1$ to obtain
$$\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+k)r^n}=r^{k}\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{nr^n}=r^{k} \left[ -\ln \left(1-\frac{1}{r} \right) -\sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{1}{nr^n} \right]$$
which is exactly what you wrote in the comment :)
